# How to play mp3 file in swift3?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have started to learn ios development and am stuck in one place. My code to play mp3 file is

```
var bombSoundEffect: AVAudioPlayer!
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "faded", ofType:"mp3")!
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)

 do {
        let sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: (url as NSURL) as URL)
        bombSoundEffect.play()

    } catch {
        print("couldn't load file :(")
    }
    if bombSoundEffect != nil {
        bombSoundEffect.stop()
        bombSoundEffect = nil
        }
```

However, when I click on the button, my file doesn't play. The song is playing perfectly normally.

Comment: Besides the original question issue you should use Bundle method url for resource with extension

Comment: You're not assigning anything to `bombSoundEffect`

Answer (score 4):

Try with the follow code:

```
var bombSoundEffect: AVAudioPlayer?

func playAudio() {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "faded", withExtension: "mp3")!

    do {
        bombSoundEffect = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        guard let bombSound = bombSoundEffect else { return }

        bombSound.prepareToPlay()
        bombSound.play()
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There's lots wrong with your code, but it's a sunny day, so try something like this…

```
func playSound() {
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "faded", withExtension: "mp3") else { return }

    let bombSoundEffect = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
    bombSoundEffect?.play()
}
```

Comment: You could use another guard statement for the `try`: `guard let audioFile = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url) else { return }`